# Creating a new T-Pose on an animated Rig

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, transforms

That's my first message over there, 'cause I'm totally Desperate.

I've spent almost 2 weeks looking for a solution on that plateform and many others, and nothing seems to work...

So, Here is my problem, if somebody can help me on that.

I've been given a mesh with its Rig, T-posed. No animation on it.
On the other side, I received Several .fbx files with animated Rig, like " Combo", "Double Hit", "Sword's attack", etc... I think you got the point.

First Issue: I noticed that the animated Rigs hasn't got the same number of Bones than the T-posed one, so I was unable to copy animations from the several . fbx files. moreover, the animated files hasn't got a proper T-pose.

"Ok, fine, anyway... I can just take one of the animated Rigs, copy all animated parts, and recreate a proper T-pose for that "Gathered Rig" to skin my mesh then." .. That's what I thought First...

So I started with one of the .fbx files
I gathered all the animation parts.
Everything's ok for the moment.
Let's see that T-pose creation.

There starts my descent to madness.

Each time I create my "New" T-pose and try to apply it / replace it on my Rig, I get that message:

"Actions on this armature will be destroy by this new rest pose as the transforms stored are relative the the old rest pose"

and the Rig just bursts appart and acts weirdly.

- I tried to clean all the constraints before applying my new rest pose ( Pose > Constraints > Clear Pose Constraints )
- I took take care to add keys, for that new T-pose, on all bones ( Shortcut "I" on Graph Editor > All Channels )
- I tried to retarget the animation on the "Gathered Rig" to the "New T-posed" One with Rokoko, but it doesn't work either.
- I tried the GYAZ animation Tools, and it doesn't work either.
- I tried to export in 3DS MAX and re-import in Blender
- I tried **"Two armature, two rest pose, fixing animations"** Topic = Doesn't work

I precise that all Frames are baked/keyed.

Nothing works. I can't replace the old T-pose without breaking all the animation.

Does it come from those "Actions" mentionned in the error message ? ( What's an Action ? Did I missed something on that ?)
Does it come from the Original Rig ?
I deeply lost...

I must precise that I'm quite novice on Blender (I started 3 months ago and I'm coming from 3DS MAX)

Please, could somebody help me ?

" Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, You're my only Hope..."
" Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, You're my only Hope..."
" Help me, Obi-Wan..."

Comment: It's a nice story but it would be easier to follow if you would shrink the text down to the issues. I'm not sure on what base the animations are created, but the actions are the animations or not? And what the error message says is this (I guess): If an animation says, rotate this bone by 30°, it is at an angle of 30° afterwards if the base was at 0° to global coordinates. But changing the rest pose so that the bone e.g. is now at 45° globally, then rotating by 30° will set it to 75° globally which results in a different animation.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Brinkmann for your answer and your time...
But I know that... 
What I'm actually looking for is:
Is there a way to reset/changing the actual Rest pose without breaking all the animation ? That's my actual problem...
And sorry for my long message. I just explained what I tried befor posting, to avoid repetition of previous Topics.
By advance, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood that, but that paragraph starting "does it come from those actions" actually made it sound as if you didn't know that... you even ask what an action is and if it comes from the original rig.

Comment: That's ok, don't worry... In fact, on that point, I was wondering if the term "Actions" was relative to some kind of "Animation Layers" similar to what you can find in 3DS MAX, and that should be Kicked off before anything else... 
From there, it would explained my Rig Issue.
I can't imagine that there's no way or trick allowing me to keep the animation while I'm changing the rest position (reminder: in order to skin easily my mesh on this animated Rig)...
I'm sure that Ancient Indian magic may holds a solution.

Comment: I've same problem currently, did you find a solution